# É correto fazer uma autenticação de usuário pela mensagem de retorno do backend?

Tags: python, json, angular, http, auth

Boa tarde, galera!

Mais cedo tirei uma dúvida referente a autenticação de usuários na minha aplicação e após algumas boas dicas consegui autenticar meu usuário, a dúvida agora é se o método aplicado para validar é correto:

Segue trecho de código:

Este é o meu backend, feito em python:

```
class Login(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('password', type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        print(args)
        password = hashlib.md5(args['password'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = (%s) and password = (%s)"
        value = (args['username'], password)
        dbcursor.execute(sql, value)
        result = dbcursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        if len(result) > 0:
            return {"message": "user valido"}
        else:
            return {"message": "user invalido"}
```

E este é meu componente em Angular:

```
 this.authService
    .authenticate(username, password)
.subscribe((res) => {
  if(res ["message"] == 'user valido') {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
  }
  else {
    console.log('user invalido')
  }
```

Basicamente envio um POST para meu servidor e ele vai checar se o usuário existe no banco, caso exista vai me retornar um JSON com a mensagem "user valido", caso não exista retorna a mensagem "user invalido". Se for valido ele vai me direcionar para a rota /dashboard.

É correto eu validar o usuario de acordo com a mensagem JSON q recebo do meu servidor igual estou fazendo ?

Comment: Por que você não retorna true/false?

Comment: Filipe, você diz pra que ao invés de retornar: return {"message": "user invalido"} ou return {"message": "user valido"} retornar um true ou false? Nesse caso eu teria que trocar o meu componente em Angular para caso receba true ou false e ai daria na mesma, não ?

Comment: return true; ou return {"message": true}

Answer (score 3):

> É correto eu validar o usuario de acordo com a mensagem JSON q recebo
>   do meu servidor igual estou fazendo ?

Não é o ideal, prefira retornar http status code de sucesso 2xx se o login foi bem sucedido e http status code 401 caso não seja possível logar.

Sugestões:

1. otimizar a query de consulta, por exemplo:

   "SELECT COUNT(username,password) FROM usuarios WHERE username = (%s) and password = (%s) LIMIT 1"
2. não faça a lógica de condicional para redirect com base em texto do body.

   res ["message"] == 'user valido'

Comment: Fala ai Pedro, beleza?
Muito boa as suas sugestões, apliquei a do SQL, porém referente a sua 2ª sugestão, em ambos os casos o meu backend retorna 2xx, sendo invalido ou não, a diferença é que se for invalido ele não me deixa ir para outra rota, como posso aplicar ?

Comment: Então, justamente o primeiro passo a ser corrigido é o backend.
Se não for para seguir essa premissa qualquer outro if/else feito no front pode ajudar, mas não é o ideal.